# If lan is connected?

Tags: linux, bash, networking, lan

I want to write a script and put it in `/etc/rc.local` so that

if lan is connected then

```
rfkill block all
```

else

```
nmcli con up id 'Network id' --nowait
```

How should I write the `if` part and how should I check for "lan is connected" ?

Comment: I think that this is better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com). That being said, the `mii-tool` command can say if a network card is connected or not, but it might not work with some cards.

Comment: @dennis-williamson Fedora and Arch

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/250061/if-lan-is-connected).

Answer (score 3):

You can check : [How to detect the physical connected state of a network cable/connector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/808560/633281)

I think at least one of the answer should work for you !