# Is there any way to detect if my LAN has been disconnected?

Tags: python, networking, lan

I want that my program prints a statement whenever there is a physical disconnection of the LAN connection from my Ethernet port.

One way is to check if there is a discontinuity in the internet connection,but i don't want the print statement to be triggered when there is a network issue from the server.Only when the wire is physically not connected to my PC.

Is there any way to implement this in Python?

Comment: Any more details? Why cannot you use standard way of doing this? Have you tried any way, and why it doesn't suit your needs? For example, on network interruption running kernel command to list devices and checking if device you are using is running.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is already an answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/808599

**EDIT:** To brief it shortly, you can use the properties in /sys/class/net/DEVICE/* to check if the wire is connected, if you run Linux.
You can just access these files using the default python methods.

For Windows, there is no way (or probably a very ugly way) to check that in Python.

Comment: You're assuming OP is using Linux. Besides, an answer should be more than just a link.

Comment: An downvote is quite hard I think. I edited the answer to be more verbose.

Comment: Oh, then I'm sorry.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17680779/5817539):

```
def is_interface_up(interface):
    addr = netifaces.ifaddresses(interface)
    return netifaces.AF_INET in addr
```

It will return True if the `interface` is up. You can check is_interface_up periodically and `print` if the returned value changes.

Comment: The OP wants to check whether the cable is connected, not if the iface is enabled.